# reducer data not rendered properly

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

Data returned from api call is:

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "id_post": 1,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post1 text",
            "parentId": 11
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "id_post": 2,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post2 text",
            "parentId": 11
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "id_post": 3,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post3 text",
            "parentId": 22
        }
    }
]
```

In the reducer the `initialState` is:

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [],         // <= Have tried with posts: {} and posts: ''
    isFetching: false,
    error: {}
}
```

The way the `posts` is populated is:

```
case "FETCHING_POSTS_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    posts: action.data
 }
```

I am able to `mapStateToProps` the posts and if I `console.log("POSTS: ", this.props.posts)` I get:

POSTS :

```
0 : {1: {…}}
1 : {2: {…}}
2 : {3: {…}}
```

Is this why the following function isn't working?:

```
renderposts = (parentId = 1) => {
  return Object.keys(this.props.posts)
    .filter(id_post => this.props.posts[id_post].parentId == parentId)
    .map((key, idx) => {
        const post = this.props.post[key];
        return(
            <View>
                <Text> { post.id_post } - { post.text } </Text>
            </View>
        );
    });
}
```

I'm not getting any error but nothing is showing either.

I'm thinking if POSTS is returned as:

```
{1: {…}}
{2: {…}}
{3: {…}}
```

in the console (so it's rendered that way), it will work. If so, how do I do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: if `posts` is an array then why are you doing `Object.keys` instead of `.map`?

Comment: Cause (1): I want to apply the filter for `parentId` and (2): Have another `onPress` functions that target the `id` of the value, so for first post, `"1"` is targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your data is an `array` not an `object` so you can't do `Object.keys` on it.
You should `.map` on it first and then loop through the object's keys.

Example:

```js
const posts = [
    {
        "1": {
            "id_post": 1,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post1 text",
            "parentId": 11
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "id_post": 2,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post2 text",
            "parentId": 11
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "id_post": 3,
            "id_user": "user01",
            "text": "post3 text",
            "parentId": 22
        }
    }
]

const View = ({postId,postText }) => {
  return(
    <div>{`${postId} - ${postText}`}</div>
  );
}

const renderposts = (parentId = 1) => {
 return posts.map(obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(id => obj[id].parentId == parentId)
    .map((key, idx) => {
        const post = obj[key];
        return(
            <View postId={post.id_post} postText={post.text}/>
        );
    });
  });
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      {renderposts(11)}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Tried this. Not working. Posts is showing as : posts: Array: https://imgur.com/a/j0PIS .. please have a look at it and advice. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a ton mate .. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `Object.keys` when `posts` is in array:

```
renderposts = (parentId = 1) => {
    return this.props.posts
        .filter((post) => post.parentId === parentId)
        .map((post) => {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text> { post.id_post } - { post.text } </Text>
                </View>
            );
       });
}
```

Comment: Error: this.props.posts.filter is not a function. I also tried `(this.props.posts).filter`

Comment: Then what is it? Could you please put a `console.log(this.props.posts)` before the return statement?

Comment: Not getting error and nothing is showing up either. console.log is array: https://imgur.com/a/j0PIS

Answer (score 0):

You can `console this.props.posts` in render method.
Sometimes your component will get rendered before data fetching from api.
To ensure this is not happening you should keep another variable `isFetched` as

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [],         
    isFetching: false,
    isFetched: false
    error: {}
}
```

and after api success call make is as true

```
case "FETCHING_POSTS_SUCCESS":
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    posts: action.data,
    isFetched: true
 }
```

So in render you can check

```
if(this.props.isFetched){
//do you code
}
else
return;
```

Comment: I am printing `this.props.posts` in render itself. I'm calling for the api on `componentWillMount` so the data is available before render is even called.